# Lighthouse reading my index instead of robots.txt

Tags: reactjs, robots.txt

I'd like to use the chrome audits tool on my React app, but it keeps saying that my robots.txt file is invalid. The thing is, the file seems to be perfectly fine, only it doesn't read robots.txt, but rather my index.html file, therefore resulting in this error :

[image]

Both files are in my /public folder, so why would it read the index file ?

Comment: Are you server-side rendering your app?

Comment: @LazarNikolic yes

Answer (score 1):

if your using **Node and Express** in order to run your **React App** project in production.
and if your **server file code** looks like below snippet, this means your are **serving same file** for all **requests**(routes). During lighthouse auditing, **browser** makes a get request to **http://localhost:5000/robots.txt** and in return it get served  with **index.html**.

```
 app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
 });
```

**To solve this problem** ,you can **add route** for **robots.txt** file, before above code snippet as shown below.

```
 app.get('/robots.txt', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'robots.txt'));
});

app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
 });
```